# Problem with Selenium no such element: Unable to locate element PageObject

Tags: selenium, junit, webdriver

I have a few que.

```
public class LoginPage {
    private WebDriver driver;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id=\"textfield-1015-inputEl\"]")
    private WebElement loginFiled;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id=\"textfield-1017-inputEl\"]")
    private WebElement passwordField;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id=\"button-1021-btnIconEl\"]")
    private WebElement signButton;

    public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver=driver;
    }

    public void init(){
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }
    public void singIntoSystemAsUser(String login,String password) {
        try {
            Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoginPage.class.getName());
            logger.log(Level.INFO,"zdes");
            loginFiled.sendKeys(login);
            passwordField.sendKeys(password);
            signButton.click();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoginPage.class.getName());
            logger.log(Level.INFO,e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

```
 @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public void browserSetup() {
        options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NONE);
        options.addArguments("start-maximized");
        options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000,
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(5000,
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(5000,
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
        driver.get("https://junior.webquik.ru/");
        loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
        homePage = new HomePage(driver);
    }
 
 @Test(description = "Sign into account")
    public  void signIntoSystem() throws InterruptedException {
      
         loginPage.singIntoSystemAsUser("U0191767","06258");
         Assert.assertEquals(driver.getTitle(),"webQUIK 7.6.2");
    }
```

After launch test a got the exception **stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document**
I have this exception a few weeks ago and i fix this just by add implicitlyWait,but now i added pageObject patter to my project
and its refuse to work,can you guys tell me what the damn hell wrong with program????
Also a tried change something by removing @FindBy from LoginPage class and add WebElemtn .. = driver.findElement instead,
and i got exception whos telling me that he cant find element on page,
but if ш manually go on page,press f12 and try to find this element i will find it.Pls help
When i tried to fix errors i got the new problem, i got the exception whos tells me that my loginPage object is null, i change code a little bit,and a give to this object the memory,but i have exception anyways.

Comment: You can see all project here that doesn't work https://github.com/KirillPochta/HelloWebDriverWithPageObject.git
And another project without pageObject he looks like some dog$it but it works fine https://github.com/KirillPochta/HelloWebDriver.git
Really hopes someone will help,deadline 9th december

Comment: you need to add wait.until(exepctedcondition.visibilityofelementlocated(By.xpath("X"))); the main probleme you are facing is that he does the action even before the page loads everything so you either wait for the page to load using js or you do what i put before or just add a Thread.sleep

Comment: Can you watch my edit pls?

Comment: All that time outs you put are useless they do nothing either you add a Thread.sleep(5000) before "loginPage.singIntoSystemAsUser("U0191767","06258");" or dont declare your WebElement outside of the @Test and use what i did in the previouse comment

Comment: I have to implement the page object pattern, so I have to initialize the webelement in a separate class, which is LoginPage,I understand what you are trying to convey,but I don't understand where to insert wait.until,tell me.

Comment: as i said use it in your @Test before you call that element so it wait s for him to show

Comment: i did this i think,but now i my test failures without any information.take a look at my edit above

Comment: when you put that xpath in your web page do you find it does it point on it ?

Comment: yes i can find it,actually when i put WebDriverWait i got exception on line when i initializate the variable,i did this in the class and if    put her into @BeforeMethod,console will tell me that this variable is null,although i give memory to her.

Comment: is it unique ??

Comment: yes.it is unique,you can take a deeper look on github  github.com/KirillPochta/HelloWebDriverWithPageObject.git

Comment: bruh,problem was cuz,id was auto generated,so i cant get this elemtns
Solution:write good locators